# How can I get a 'Clone in Mac' function for GitHub Gists?

Tags: macos, github, bookmarklet

Github has a 'Clone in Mac' button for repos:

[image]

Does anyone know any bookmarklet or Chrome Extension to be able to do the same for gists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL of the button is:

```
github-mac://openRepo/https://github.com/user/repo
```

Since Gists are repositories too, the URL for Gists would be:

```
github-mac://openRepo/https://gist.github.com/123456
```

Thus, your Javascript code is:

```
window.location = "github-mac://openRepo/" + document.location.href
```

And your bookmarklet code:

```
javascript:(function(){window.location=%22github-mac://openRepo/%22+document.location.href})();
```

To create this bookmarklet, simply go to Bookmarks Manager (or ⌥⌘B), and add your link:

[image]

This will now work for all Git repositories, even the normal ones.

Comment: See my answer I made a userscript for this with your instructions. Works like a charm. I've validated your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I made a userscript to automatically add 'Clone in Mac' button on gists.

[image]

https://gist.github.com/3227047

—

And of course, you can clone it in Mac :p